# Flexbox Responsive Navigation Issue

Tags: css, flexbox, nav

Im trying to build a responsive navigation using flexbox. I have the desktop version looking fine. But when it enters the phone media query, I want the order of the items to change. I want the logo above the navigation links on its own line, and the 4 nav links below centrally aligned. I have tried everything so I come to the great people of stack overflow for help.

link to code:

http://codepen.io/Davabo/pen/EKNBMz

```
* {margin:0; padding:0; font-weight: normal;}

$phone: 480px;

@mixin phone {
  @media (max-width: #{$phone}) {
    @content;
  }
}


.menu{

    display:flex;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    a{text-decoration:none;color: black;padding:20px;}

    & > div {

      flex: 2;
      font-size: 20px;
      text-align: center;
      padding-top: 30px; 
    }

    .logo {
      width: 100%;
      flex: 1;
      padding-top: 40px; 
      text-align: center;
    }

            @include phone {

                .logo {

                 background: pink;
                 text-align: center;
                 flex: 5;
                 flex-grow: 5;
                } 

                .nav1, .nav2 {
                  flex-basis: 100%;
                  width: 100%;

                }
            }

  }
```

I have attached what I want the phone navigation to look like:

http://prntscr.com/afwt0g

Thank you so much for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a combination of the `order` and `flex-grow` properties on the items e.g.

```
@media screen and {max-width: 480px){
    .menu{flex-wrap: wrap;}
    .logo{order: 1; flex-grow: 2;}
    .nav1{order: 2; flex-grow: 1;}
    .nav2{order: 3; flex-grow: 1;}
}
```

`Order` rearranges the order of items within a flex container.

`Flex-grow` works out the sizing of an element compared to it's siblings within a flex container

`wrap` on the container forces items to wrap when the container width forces it

Here is a link to a good flexbox resource: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/